# Printing pdf conditionally from a web page

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a pdf embedded inside the web page like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id = "pdfFrame" name="pdfFrame" data="sample.pdf#print=true" width="800" height="800"/>
</body>
```

This pdf has embedded javascript which opens pdf print dialog on load of pdf.
I want to make this call conditional and let web page pass the condition.

So is there a way to pass a parameter to the pdf and then let embedded javascript access that to decide whether to show print dialog or not